# How to display search results with one click not two?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm creating an Android app that has a search feature that search an online database. When I want to search something though, I have to double click on the search button for the correct results to be displayed. I believe the issue is with the fact that I'm using an Asynctask function in the onClick for the button. This is my onClick:

```
public void onSearchClick(View view) throws TVDBOutboundConnectionException {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // fetch data
        new SeriesSearchTask().execute(text.getText().toString());
    } else {
        // display error
    }

    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ALTS.size(); i++) {
        list.add(ALTS.get(i).getSeriesName());
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
                    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            list.remove(item);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            view.setAlpha(1);
                        }
                    });
        }

    });

}
```

This is my Asynctask method:

```
private class SeriesSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            ALTS = DB.searchSeriesInTVDB(urls[0], Language.ENGLISH);
            return Integer.toString(ALTS.size());
        } catch (TVDBOutboundConnectionException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    }
}
```

So my question is how do I get the method to display the correct results on one search click, as that would be normal and expected. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is due to how AsyncTask works.
The code inside your AsyncTask runs on a separate thread and therefore the lines afterwards are executed **instantly** before your AsyncTask has even finished doing his job.

To update the UI after your AsyncTask has finished you'd need to execute the code inside the `onPostExecute()` method.

Just move the code afterwards into an own method:

```
public void updateUi(){
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < ALTS.size(); i++) {
        list.add(ALTS.get(i).getSeriesName());
    }

    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    //...
}
```

Then handover your Activity to the AsyncTask and run this method on the UI Thread after execution.

```
private class SeriesSearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    MyActivity mActivity;

    public SeriesSearchTask(final MyActivity _activity){
        mActivity = _activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            ALTS = DB.searchSeriesInTVDB(urls[0], Language.ENGLISH);
            return Integer.toString(ALTS.size());
        } catch (TVDBOutboundConnectionException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //updating the UI here
        if(mActivity != null){
            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    mActivity.updateUi();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

An even better solution imho would be to use an event bus like [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) to notify the Activity. Check out their website, it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll read up about the event bus as it would be nice to learn about for future reference.